# Angular8 ngFor Child Data Binding Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, binding, components, ngfor

I am not new to Angular and would expect this code to render the data provided by the parent (maybe Angular8 changed syntax). Maybe I am new to this. The specific question is why a child component listed in a parent's ngFor loop with data binding is not rendering the data in the list.

The console.logs show the arrays.

The child component has a check box which is rendered; the person name, status and department are not rendered. I followed these exact steps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGStS1hD5Y4 and this is the code:

parent.component.html:

```
<div>Json results:</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Department</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <app-people
        *ngFor="let person of people"
        [personItem]="person"
      ></app-people>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

parent.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PeopleService } from './people.service';
import { People } from './people';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  people = [];
  avatars = [];
  constructor(private peopleService: PeopleService, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http
      .get(`assets/people.json`)
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);

        for (let key in data)
          if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) this.people.push(data[key]);
      });

    this.http
      .get(`assets/avatars.json`)
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);

        for (let key in data)
          if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) this.avatars.push(data[key]);
      });
  }
```

child.component.html:

```
<div class="people-container">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    [checked]="person.isSelected"
    (change)="complete.emit($event.target.checked)"
  />
  <span [ngClass]="{ selected: person.isSelected }" class="person-title">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let img of avatars">
          <td *ngIf="personItem.id == img.id"><img [src]="img.avatar" /></td>
        </ng-container>
        <td>{{ personItem.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ personItem.status }}</td>
        <td>{{ personItem.department }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </span>

  <button (click)="remove.emit(person.id)">X</button>
</div>
```

child.component.ts:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy
} from "@angular/core";
import { People } from "../people";
@Component({
  selector: "app-people",
  templateUrl: "./people.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./people.component.css"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PeopleComponent implements OnInit {
  people = [];
  avatars = [];
  @Input() personItem: People;
  @Output() select = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Output() remove = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

If anything else is needed please ask.

Comment: share the People ts file

Comment: your code should be ok, check your model property name user in assigning values and binding in html are in right syntax.

Comment: The reason why it might have not been rendered is could be due to the condition in the `*ngIf` directive is `false`. i can also see that you are calling the get request in `AppComponent` and storing the array but have not passed it to the child component where you are iterating it in a `*ngFor`.

Comment: @user3875919 I believe that array is meant to be passed using the data binding of [personItem] = person in the parent and then personItem.name etc. in the child. Since that is not working, how else could I get the array to the child? It must remain in the parent component for the ngFor loop. When I added the array to both the parent and child components, console.log rays were output once for each of the array items.

Comment: @kamprasad- I think you are correct, but also my contract in the People model is matched with how I am calling attributes in the child component. I don't see a problem that is causing the data to not render and it compiles without error. What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your child(s) component is using the strategy OnPush, meaning that everytime an input change it wont update the component. To fix that simply add a OnChanges life cycle, inject in the constructor the ChangeDetectionRef and trigger it in the OnChanges.

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-people",
  templateUrl: "./people.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./people.component.css"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PeopleComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  people = [];
  avatars = [];
  @Input() personItem: People;
  @Output() select = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Output() remove = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectionRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngOnChanges() { 
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Or you could just remove the `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` line and everything should work fine.

Comment: "Property 'detectChanges' does not exist on type 'ChangeDetectionStrategy'".

Comment: You have to inject ChangeDetectionRef, not ChangeDetectionStrategy

Comment: I added ChangeDetectorRef to the child component imports and implemented this and still no response in child data.

Comment: Ok, and you remove the changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush line?

Comment: Yeah, tried with and without. I think something weird is going on.

Comment: That's strange. It would be amazing if you can create a stackblitz for me so I can debug it.

Comment: STACKBLITZ- This is the version of it working (but Stackblitz is unfriendly with json data so if you copy/paste the code files down to a local angular-cli project you will see it working, but I had issues local hosting with a project download): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g3jhbf. I am trying to turn that version into this version so that I can have individual click events for each json object listed rather than click events for the entire list; I am trying to use a child component in an ngFor loop: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swzqhi

Comment: I'll look up to that and I'll let you know!